# I cannot get new updates

Tags: 12.04, lts

Pakettitietoja ei voitu alustaa

Pakettitietoja alustettaessa tapahtui virhe jota ei voitu korjata.

Ilmoita tästä virheraportilla paketille "update-manager", ja sisällytä raporttiin seuraava virheviesti:

`E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/lists/fi.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en, E:Pakettiluettelonn tai tilatiedoston avaaminen tai jäsennys epäonnistui.`

English translation (using Google Translate) -

> Package information could not be initialized
>
> Initializing the package information An error occurred that could not
>   be repaired.
>
> Report this error report package "update-manager", and include in the
>   report the following error message:
>
> E:Encountered a section with no Package: header, E:Problem with
>   MergeList
>   /var/lib/apt/lists/fi.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_main_i18n_Translation-en,
>   E:The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I finally made it. Now it's working properly again!

Answer (score 0):

When you run `sudo apt-get update`, you are updating the details about the packages which are stored at `/var/lib/apt/lists`.

Here it is told that a section is damaged about package details. So it is corrupted. Best thing is to remove the folder and then make a new folder.

When updating is running the downloading details are first stored at a sub directory named `partial`. So that sub directory also needed to be created while making the new directory.

Run :

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists && sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial && sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: You should add details on what these commands do and why you think that this would solve the issue. :)